# Override Entity edit pages with Panels

Tags: panels, entities

Panels comes with a "Node add/edit form" template that, as the name states, lets you edit the add/edit form of a node.

How can override the add/edit form of entities created via [Entity Construction Kit (ECK)](https://drupal.org/project/eck).

My users can create new instances of an entity, via a node through the [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). I would like to use panels to customise the entity add/edit screen when it is called via this form.